# postgres trigger add condition to audit function to fill user with database user

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I work with postgresql 11

I have a table **employee_audit** and I run a trigger and it work succesffuly.

this is the code :

```
CREATE TABLE audit_log.employee_audit
(
    operation char(15) NOT NULL,
    stamp timestamp NOT NULL,
    userid text ,
    id character varying(15) NOT NULL,
  tel character varying(15),
  fax character varying(15),
  mail character varying(100)
  created_by character varying(50),
  created_date timestamp without time zone,
  last_modified_by character varying(50),
  last_modified_date timestamp without time zone
   
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE audit_log.employee_audit
    OWNER to postgres;
    
------------------------------------- Fin création table employee_audit

------- Create the function to insert into the log table
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION audit_log.process_employee_audit() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $employee_audit$
    BEGIN
        --
        -- Create a row in emp_audit to reflect the operation performed on emp,
        -- make use of the special variable TG_OP to work out the operation.
        --
        IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
            INSERT INTO audit_log.employee_audit SELECT 'DELETE', now(), NEW.last_modified_by, OLD.*;
            RETURN OLD;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
          IF (TG_WHEN='AFTER') THEN
            INSERT INTO audit_log.employee_audit SELECT 'AFTER UPDATE', now(), NEW.last_modified_by, NEW.*;
          ELSIF (TG_WHEN='BEFORE') THEN
            INSERT INTO audit_log.employee_audit SELECT 'BEFORE UPDATE', now(), OLD.last_modified_by, OLD.*;
          END IF;
          RETURN NEW;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
            INSERT INTO audit_log.employee_audit SELECT 'INSERT', now(), NEW.created_by, NEW.*;
            RETURN NEW;
        END IF;
        RETURN NULL; -- result is ignored since this is an AFTER trigger
    END;
$employee_audit$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-------- Create AFTER trigger on the employee table
CREATE TRIGGER employee_audit
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON public.employee
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE audit_log.process_employee_audit();

-------- Crete Before Trigger on the employee Table
CREATE TRIGGER employee_audit_before
Before UPDATE ON public.employee
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE audit_log.process_employee_audit();
```

I have a use case in the update specially in " **AFTER UPDATE** "

the column **userid** will be filled by  **NEW.last_modified_by**

in my application in update function I filled this column **last_modified_by**
by the connected user .

this is the code :

```
public UnitDTO updateUnit(UnitDTO unitDTO) {

    User user = userService.getUserWithAuthorities().get();
    
    Unit unit = unitMapper.toEntity(unitDTO);
    unit.setLastModifiedBy(user.getEmployee().getId());
    unit.setLastModifiedDate(LocalDateTime.ofInstant(new Date().toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault()));
    
    unit = unitRepository.save(unit);


    return newUnitDTO;
}
```

and in the table **employee_audit**  the column **userid** contain the correct data which is the
connected user of the application ( who make the update ).

my problem now when I connect directly to the database and I update some data in **employee** table

in **employee_audit** I found that the column **userid** contain the data of **last_modified_by**
column which is already insered .

the correct value should be the user of the database because I make the update
directly in database
or should be empty

I thing that I should make some condition in the trigger in 'AFTER UPDATE' case
( so change **NEW.last_modified_by** )

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong approach about logging who did what and when. You cannot rely on your application doing this, precisely because, like you are taking notice right now, you cannot guarantee every query will be generated from inside it.

First of all, you need to make your application so that each application user is a login in the database. Postgres has a [`session_user`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-info.html) variable that returns said login (only superuser can change its value).
->If your application connects using a generic login + a user record stored in a table you created, you need to change that.

While you are correcting this issue, you could also make the auditing system more generic.

#### Step 1: Create a generic table and trigger function to handle all the audits you may want:

```
CREATE TABLE audit_template
(
    created_by name NOT NULL,
    created_date timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    last_modified_by name NOT NULL,
    last_modified_date timestamp without time zone  NOT NULL
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION audit_set_user()
RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
VOLATILE NOT LEAKPROOF
AS $BODY$
    BEGIN
        IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
            NEW.created_by := SESSION_USER;
            NEW.created_date := current_timestamp;
        END IF;
        NEW.last_modified_by := SESSION_USER;
        NEW.last_modified_date := current_timestamp;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$BODY$;
```

Note that I declared the table with `NOT NULL` and without default values for the columns, since the trigger will take care of filling the missing bits.

#### Step 2: Create your `employee` table and the associated `BEFORE` trigger:

`Employee` inherits `audit_template`; using inheritance is optional (you could also add the columns directly to the table) but I find it makes it easier to ensure many tables behave the same; it basically removes risks of introducing small involuntary differences across many tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employee
(
    stamp timestamp NOT NULL,
    userid text ,
    id character varying(15) NOT NULL,
    tel character varying(15),
    fax character varying(15),
    mail character varying(100)
) INHERITS (audit_template);

CREATE TRIGGER employee_fill_audit
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON employee
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE audit_set_user();
```

At this stage, the trigger will ensure audit data is correctly filled in the `employee` table.
BTW, I have not changed the columns' definition but it feels some unique constraints are missing there (e.g. on `id`, `mail`, etc).

#### Step 3: Create the employee audit table to log the changes + associated trigger function and `AFTER` trigger.

```sql
CREATE TABLE employee_audit
(
    stamp timestamp NOT NULL,
    userid text ,
    id character varying(15) NOT NULL,
    tel character varying(15),
    fax character varying(15),
    mail character varying(100),
    OP TEXT NOT NULL
) INHERITS (audit_template);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION employee_audit_log()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
    BEGIN
        If TG_OP = 'INSERT' THEN
            INSERT INTO employee_audit SELECT New.*, TG_OP;
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO employee_audit SELECT Old.*, TG_OP;
        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
    END;
$BODY$;

CREATE TRIGGER employee_log_to_audit
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON employee
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE employee_audit_log();
```

Note: just in case I misunderstood step 2 and `employee` needs not have the 4 audit columns, you can:

- remove `INHERIT` from the creation of `employee`,
- attach the trigger to `employee_audit` instead of `employee`.

  That will make the functions be called in a different order but will work just as well: `employee_log_to_audit` will be triggered first (`INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE` on `employee`), then as a record gets insert on `employee_audit`, `employee_fill_audit` will be called to fill the audit fields.

If it was fine, there is an alternative to creating the `employee_audit`, where it is done this way (along with some changes on the trigger):

```sql
CREATE TABLE employee_audit
(
    OP TEXT NOT NULL
) INHERITS (employee);
```

It is because I thought you may want to test this alternative that I put the `OP` column last in the previous definition of `employee_audit`.

I am not a very big fan of it though, because it causes `SELECT * FROM employee` to return the content of both tables. To get the content from `employee` without `employee_audit`, you have to use the query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM ONLY employee
```

#### Step 4: Watch it work.

I let you do `SELECT * FROM employee` and `SELECT * FROM employee_audit` after each of the queries below:

```sql
INSERT INTO employee(stamp, id) VALUES (now(), 'Some id');

UPDATE employee SET id = 'Some other id';

DELETE FROM employee;
```

Comment: thank you for your response,
I try to use SESSION_USER in NEW.last_modified_by but all time it return the postgres user.

juste not , I work with java spring boot and it use the Connection pool concept.

I think that I should use case when condition in the audit_log.process_employee_audit() function
 to check  if the user is from database
( in my example : postgres user ) or is from application.
maybee will check using process of the user

Comment: What do you mean by "process of the user"? If you can explain that part, I can edit my answer. PS: I hope (for you) that the connections of your pool do not use `postgres` to connect. That would be the best way to get infinite data breaches, have your database wiped cleaned or rendered inaccessible and receive a request for a ransom.

Comment: Something I forgot to ask: just to be sure, is you application something that runs on a server, with users connecting to it? or is it something that runs on each user's computer and you need to keepa pool of connection for each client?

Comment: thank you a lot for your answers and sorry for the late,
 I create new user " testUser " and I connect the application using this user.
 
I work with web application and I use java spring boot which is running in tomcat server. As you know with web application it use a pool connection.

 And with java I can get the connected user using this code "
   User user = userService.getUserWithAuthorities().get();"
 And the application is connected to the database using user datatabase " testUser ".

Comment: for any update from application I don't have 
a problem because from application I file last_modified_by  in employee table

 and it will be used in employee_audit .
 
 my only problem is when the update is directly from database 
 in this case the userId should be " testUser "
 
 and I want to do something in the trigger to khow if the update is from application or 
 from datatabase directly using for example process type ( from pgadmin or from java application ) ....

Comment: 1. When you test your application, make sure to create a role whose name corresponds to an application user id (it might be something you already did for `userService.getUserWithAuthorities().get()` to work, I can't tell). 2. Grant that role to `testUser`. 3. Change your application so that it does `SET ROLE [...]` before the query is executed but does not pass the user name to the query. 4. Try `CURRENT_USER` instead of `SYSTEM_USER` and have your application do `SET ROLE`. If you have done all of the above correctly, that should make the trigger work the way you want.